# List of Android apps

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Is it possible to get list of Android apps which are releasing daily or weekly. I searched in PlayStore, but I could not find such feature

Answer (score 2):

- [Appbrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=en) a front end for Google Play , gives a better filtering capability completed to play store but you may not be able to see on *daily / weekly* basis

You can filter for *new* apps as shown, further by *categories*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Play Store does not have the feature of filtering apps by their release date (i.e. day or week), however, you can use this URL to check newly released apps:

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/new?hl=en

Hundreds of apps are released daily, so it is not possible to find them all using this screen but you can get the apps which are new and popular too. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

In google play store click on New apps and games category